# How to create a resizable custom twisted shape quadrilateral which can crop Doc image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, gesturedetector, flutter-image

I want to create a customizable quadrilateral shape crop window. A user can adjust this crop window to form a twisted quadrilateral to get perfect crop image. Also i want that if user drags center point of a line then the line can bend at that particular point from sides.I want this feature as i have to drag documents/bills from images.
The crop window can be of shape like given below. Here the blue dots are points which can dragged to make perfect crop window.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **ScanbotSdk** or **GeniusScan**, they are actually paid packages (can be used in demo version) but they are very good and efficient.
Nextly, I would like to suggest **edge detections** or you can try **scanny** package, they are free but, as you can guess it, they are not much efficient or accurate while detecting the edges.

I hope you got what you were looking for

PS - ScanbotSdk or GeniusScan, I haven't tried them personally so they might include the feature of dragging and placing the corner points, like what you actually want.